# Android game Image format

Tags: android

I have a problem with an image for an android game. The problem is not a problem with the code because the code that I use I took from a book (Beginning Android 4 Games Developer).

The problem is this: I know the format that I have to use in android: png, but I don't know the settings for this format that I have to use (like RGB565...). Because if I use simply png, when I run the game the images are not good. So I need someone to explain to which settings I need to use for images for android games.

P.S The software that I used is photoshop. If there is better software for this purpose tell me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a strong misconception in your understanding of Android and how it implements graphics. You are not constrained to .png for nearly any of your development. The .png and .9.png are only enforced strictly for managing drawable constants.

Android uses Java and has the capability to utilize nearly any graphical format. In particular native support for .bmp, .png, and .jpg are present for every device and Android OS version. You may even create your graphics in realtime byte by byte.

As for a good image editor, there are a number out there. I often use a combination of GIMP and Photoshop, myself.

Hope this helps,

FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have a question, what you mean when you say "You may even create your graphics in realtime byte by byte" and what format do you advise me to use?

Comment: That's kind of the issue. You may use whatever format you want. Depends on your needs (size, speed, ease, etc.). There are a ton of great examples that use any of the above formats. There are also many libraries that cover other formats as well. You may even use pure Java libraries to do so. It all converts to Bitmap in the end.

Comment: What I mean when I say create a graphic in realtime byte by byte. I may instantiate an array of bytes, send it whatever byte values I want and render it as a graphic. There are really very few limitations... only when to draw something and where...